# Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (5, 5, 512) and (19, 19, 512)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to build Resnet50 model here's a part of my Resnet50 code

```
def Resnet50_Model(*args,**kwargs):
    #Load Model if we saved one
    if(os.path.isfile("F:/4th Year/Computational Intelligence/Task/Project/resent50.h5")==True):
        return keras.models.load_model("F:/4th Year/Computational Intelligence/Task/Project/resent50.h5")
    input=Input(shape=(150, 150, 3))
    out=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(7,7),strides=(2,2),padding='same',input_shape=(150,150,3),activation='relu',name="conv1")(input)
    out=BatchNormalization(name='bn1')(out)
    out=Activation('relu',name='relu1')(out)
    out=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same',name='pool1')(out)
    out=conv_block(out,[1,3,1],[64,64,256],stage=2,block='a',stride=(1,1))
    out=identity_block(out,[1,3,1],[64,64,256],stage=2,block="b",stride=(1,1))
    out = identity_block(out, [1, 3, 1], [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block="b", stride=(1, 1))
    out=conv_block(out,[1,3,1],[128,128,512],stage=3,block="c")
```

Here's conv-block code

```
def conv_block(out,kernel,filter,stage,block,stride=(2,2)):
    filter1,filter2,filter3=filter
    kernel1,kernel2,kernel3=kernel
    conv_name="conv"+str(stage)+block
    bn_name = "bn" + str(stage) + block

    #--------------------
    tmp=Conv2D(filters=filter1,kernel_size=(kernel1,kernel1),strides=stride,activation='relu',name=conv_name+"_1")(out)
    tmp=BatchNormalization(name=bn_name+"_1")(tmp)
    tmp=Activation('relu')(tmp)
    tmp = Conv2D(filters=filter2, kernel_size=(kernel2,kernel2), strides=stride, padding='same', activation='relu',name=conv_name+"_2")(tmp)
    tmp = BatchNormalization(name=bn_name+"_2")(tmp)
    tmp = Activation('relu')(tmp)
    tmp = Conv2D(filters=filter3, kernel_size=(kernel3,kernel3), strides=stride, activation='relu',name=conv_name+"_3")(tmp)
    tmp = BatchNormalization(name=bn_name+"_3")(tmp)
    tmp = Activation('relu')(tmp)
    #--------------------
    tmp2= Conv2D(filters=filter3, kernel_size=(kernel3,kernel3), strides=stride, activation='relu',name=conv_name+"_4")(out)
    tmp2 = BatchNormalization(name=bn_name+"_4")(tmp2)
    #tmp=MaxPool2D(pool_size=(3,3),strides=(2,2),padding='same',name='pool1')
    conc=add([tmp,tmp2])
    final=Activation('relu')(conc)
    return final
```

so whenever I run my code it gives me this error:->
Inputs have incompatible shapes. Received shapes (5, 5, 512) and (19, 19, 512)
on this line

```
---->out=conv_block(out,[1,3,1],[128,128,512],stage=3,block="c")
---->conc=add([tmp,tmp2])
```

So how can i solve this error

Comment: Well, it suggests, that `tmp` and `tmp2` have different sizes, the input size to be precise. Your code is in desperate need of spaces and empty lines for better readability, then it might be more obvious where the mistake is at

Comment: I guess the error is that `tmp2` is passing through another convolution (`tmp2= Conv2D(filters=filter3, [...]`) with strides = 2, thus the image size gets smaller. You could try setting `strides = 1` and `padding = 'SAME'` in that convolution

Comment: @Bahy123, as suggested above by Chillston, please try changing `tmp2= Conv2D(filters=filter3, [...])`    to    `tmp2= Conv2D(filters=filter3, kernel_size=(kernel3,kernel3), strides=1, padding='SAME', activation='relu',name=conv_name+"_4")(out)`  and let us know if the issue still persists. Thank you!